# Android Xamarin: how to grant BindTelecomConnectionService permission?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an issue making phone calls from the foreground service and this is [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60064193/xamarin-android-10-call-from-foreground-service-stops-working-when-screen-is-of?noredirect=1#comment106306882_60064193) about that.

As suggested in the comments of the question - I started testing the [ConnectionService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService). I added BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE permission to the manifest file.

Declared `MyConnectionService` class:

```
[Service(Permission= Manifest.Permission.BindTelecomConnectionService)]
public class MyConnectionService : ConnectionService
{

}
```

And then I run this code:

```
var telecomManager = (TelecomManager)GetSystemService(Context.TelecomService);
var phoneAccountHandle = new PhoneAccountHandle(
    new ComponentName(this.PackageName, nameof(MyConnectionService)), "MyApp");
var builder = new PhoneAccount.Builder(phoneAccountHandle, "CustomAccount");
var phoneAccount = builder.Build();
telecomManager.RegisterPhoneAccount(phoneAccount);
```

The `telecomManager.RegisterPhoneAccount(phoneAccount);` gives me an exception:

```
Java.Lang.SecurityException: 'PhoneAccount connection service requires BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE permission.'
```

Ok - it seems the permission is not granted. Testing it with `ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission()` - yes, it is not granted.

Making a permission request with `ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions()` - it is executed and that's it.
No permission request on the screen, not way to grant on the application permission page.

My question is - how to grant this kind of permission?

Environmet:

- Android API Level 28
- Testing on Google Pixel 2 XL phone running Android 10

Comment: You need to declare the `BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE` perm via the manifest for your `ConnectionService` subclass

Comment: @SushiHangover I'm registering it in this way  [Service(Permission= Manifest.Permission.BindTelecomConnectionService)]
        public class MyConnectionService : ConnectionService {} - still same result.

Comment: You will need to use the `Name` parameter for your `ServiceAttribute`, see this answer (#3) for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49415199/4984832

Answer (score 0):

Comments by [SushiHangover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4984832/sushihangover) helped a lot and pointed to the right direction. In order to make the solution work and avoid the exception, the [ConnectionService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService) should have proper name (fully qualified Java class name) and permission declaration. These values can be added either in the manifest file or by declaring the [ServiceAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.app.serviceattribute?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9) in the code:

```
 [Service(
      Name = "com.sample.MyApp.MyConnectionService", 
      Permission = Manifest.Permission.BindTelecomConnectionService, 
      Enabled = true)]
 public class MyConnectionService : ConnectionService
 {
 }
```

Secondly, the name of the service must be exact when creating [ComponentName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.content.componentname?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9) instance:

```
var telecomManager = (TelecomManager)GetSystemService(Context.TelecomService);
var phoneAccountHandle = new PhoneAccountHandle(
    new ComponentName(this.PackageName, "com.sample.MyApp.MyConnectionService"), 
    "GateOpener");
var builder = new PhoneAccount.Builder(phoneAccountHandle, "CustomAccount");
var phoneAccount = builder.Build();
telecomManager.RegisterPhoneAccount(phoneAccount);
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: This PhoneAccountHandle is not enabled for this user!